# backwards arrow in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am working on a project in Haskell coding for a basic AI which plays checkers. I have stumbled across a backwards arrow or `<-` which I'm a bit confused what it means or how to rewrite in terms of basic pattern matching

```
Moves :: GameState -> [[Move]]
Moves gs = concatMap treeToMove (Moves' gs)
 where
  Moves' gs = [Moves2 (turn gs) (gs, moves)  | moves <- legalMoves gs]
```

Also, is there another way to write the `concatMap` function in terms of more basic means?

Comment: Classic Haskell thing. For example, see under “I'm a list comprehension” in [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out).

Comment: haskell's `[a | a <- some_list]` is pythons' `[a for a in sime_list]` if it helps

Comment: Let me add that the line `Moves' gs = [ .... ]` is rather weird. This is a type error except in a few rather uncommon cases (pattern synonyms, monad comprehensions). Are you sure the code you posted is correct? Was that meant to be `moves' gs = ...` instead?

Comment: You could always rewrite the `concatMap` function in terms of `concat` and `map`, `concatMap f xs == concat (map f xs)`.